# Where does Gmail store saved templates?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

After doing some research, I found that the templates are saved in Google Drive, so I designed some templates and saved them in a folder in Google Drive. But, when I tried to insert a template using `Compose > Template > Insert template` I didn't find a way to access Google Drive folders.

Is there a place outside Google Drive where Gmail templates are stored?

Comment: Is it possible that you confused instructions for using a 3rd party tool/extension  with native Gmail tools?  If you have any links to the research you did please provide so I can review.

Answer (score 0):

## Gmail Templates

Gmail templates are not saved in Google Drive.

1. **Create/Manage Templates in Gmail**
   Template management is done through Gmail's message compose interface
2. **Draft Emails in Google Docs**
   Google Docs offers an *alternative* to Gmail templates allowing users to draft and collaborate on *documents* used as email templates.
3. **Gmail API**
   Google exposes access to message templates that can be accessed using Google Apps Script.

### 1.  Create/Manage Templates in Gmail

*Source:* **[Google Workspace Learning Center, Tips for sending email](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/11339703?hl=en#send)**

> #### Send pre-written emails with email templates
>
> Tired of typing the same reply every time someone sends you an email with a common
> question? Compose your reply once and save the email as a template.
> You can also include your signature. Later, you can open the template
> and send it again with just a few clicks.
>
> **Note:** Email templates are available only in Gmail on the web. Templates aren't available in Gmail mobile apps.
>
> #### Enable templates
>
> 1. Open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/).
> 2. At the top right, click **[Settings [image: Settings button] >
>    See all settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general)**.
> 3. At the top, click **[Advanced](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/advanced)**.
> 4. In the **Templates** section, select **Enable**.
> 5. At the bottom, click **Save Changes**.
>
> #### Create or change a template
>
> 1. Open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) and click **Compose**.
> 2. In the **Compose** window, enter your template text.
> 3. Click **More**[image: More button]**> Templates**
> 4. Choose an option:
>
>    - To create a new template, click **Save draft as template > Save as new template**.
>    - To change a previously saved template, click **Save draft as template** and under **Overwrite Template**, choose a template and
>      click **Save** to overwrite it.
> 5. (Optional) To send an email, compose your message and click **Send**.
>
> #### Insert a template
>
> 1. Open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) and click **Compose**.
> 2. Click **More**[image: More button]**> Templates**
> 3. To insert a template, under **Insert template**, choose a saved template to insert in your email.
> 4. Compose the rest of your message and click Send.

### 2.  Draft Emails in Google Docs

*Source:* **[Google Docs Editors Help, Use Google Docs to draft emails](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/11930385?hl=en)**

> From your computer, you can use Google Docs to write
> an email draft and quickly preview it in Gmail.
>
> #### Work with email drafts on Google Docs
>
> 1. On your computer, open a [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/).
> 2. At the top left, click **Insert** > **Building blocks** > **Email draft**.
>
>    - You can also type "@email" in the doc and press **Enter**.
> 3. To add recipients in the "To" field, type "@" and search your contacts, or type out email addresses.
> 4. You can add a subject line, write text in the email body, and format your draft.
>
>    - **Tip:** You can collaborate with others in your doc to write an email draft. Learn more about how to [share access to your doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822).
>
> #### Preview and send your email draft in Gmail
>
> 1. At the top left of the email draft, click the **Preview in Gmail** button [image: Preview in Gmail Preview in Gmail].
>      [image: Image Description]
> 2. In the pop-up Gmail window, you can make additional changes to your email.
> 3. When you are ready, click **Send**.
>
>    - **Important:** The email draft will be sent from the account you are logged into.

### 3. Gmail API

According to this Stack Overflow answer, [Are Gmail email Templates accessible by Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69135002), Gmail templates are drafts that are hidden from the Gmail Web App GUI but can be accessed via the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides). This would require you to write your own Script or find an existing third-party tool with the functionality you want.

- [Build web apps and automate tasks with Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)
- [Gmail API Overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides)
- [Link to try the users.drafts.list method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D#authorization-scopes)
  Results include both drafts and templates
  Empty the drafts folder to return only templates.
  [image: The online try Method interface for users.drafts.list]

Answer (score -1):

While the storage quota is shared, the services of Drive, Gmail, Photo, and Backup are stored not within your actual drive folder.

You can view your Google Drive storage quota here:
https://one.google.com/storage