# Extract images from message templates

Tags: gmail

I am supporting a Gmail user who has saved 50 message templates, the maximum allowed.

I want to extract all the images from the templates, and save them to a directory `attachments` on my PC.

My current approach:

1. In Gmail, compose a new message;
2. Insert a template;
3. Use the browser's `Save as > Webpage, Complete` option to save the page locally;
4. Identify the relevant `unnamed(n).png` images from the newly saved files;
5. Add those identified images to my `attachments` directory;
6. Repeat steps 2 - 5 for each remaining template.

Is there a 'bulk' way of doing this?  Ideally, I would like to find Gmail's templates directory.

Comment: I edited your post to make it clear to other users and use Gmail's terminology. If I misinterpreted anything please correct and accept my apologies.

Comment: Please note that the images you are saving are previews which will impact the quality (compression) and even the resolution (dimensions). See my answer to [Directly copy attached image without the need to download it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171640/) regarding preview rendering of images.

Comment: If you follow the duplicate link [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159363/) (**3. Gmail API**) includes a link that allows you to test the `users.drafts.list` method which could be combined with the script from the following answer [How can I extract inline images from a Gmail email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73103829). If you go a scripting route, keep in mind the distinction between inline images, attached images, or both.